# Need "Method return type" of data selected with LINQ from DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a method, which takes data received from database, and it takes only data which has a specific day:

```
private static **return type** FilterDataByDay(DataTable dt, string nameOfTheDay)
    {
         var data = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new
            {
                code = x.Field<string>("Code"),
                day= x.Field<string>("Day"),
                name= x.Field<string>("Name"),
                startTime= x.Field<int>("StartTime"),
                endTime= x.Field<int>("EndTime")

            })
                                    .Where(x => x.day.Equals(nameOfTheDay))
                                    .ToList();

        return data ;
    }
```

The problem is I don't know how to return data from this method, that other method could take it ant print it out, every element like of each row, it should let me print something like:

```
    foreach(var variable in "the retuned data from method")
    {
     Console.WriteLine(variable.code +" "+ variable.day + ..etc...
    }
```

Comment: you're using `anonymous type` in a wrong way. It should not be returned by a method. Just define your own class containing all the properties you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing about anonymous types is that they're not named, e.g. anonymous.

The best course of action is to define your own class with the appropriate properties after which you can return `IEnumerable<SomeClass>`.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a Wrapper class and then you'll have `IEnumerable<MyClass>`

or you can use `IEnumerable<dynamic>` , but this way - you wont have intellisence.

Answer (score 2):

Defining a proper class that would encapsulate the loaded data is probably the best way to go. But if you are dealing with data you will not need later and you don't pass them to much around, you can leverage the [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) class. It will look slightly awkward, but if it is just your code and it is not a part of a public API then it is also usable.

Your return type would then be `IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string, string, int, int>>`